# Application of law of total probability for continuous random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, continuous-data, notation

Consider 3 random variables $Y,V,T$, with supports $\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{V},\mathcal{T}$, respectively.

Let

- $P_{Y,V}$ denote the probability distribution of $(Y,V)$
- $P_{V}$ denote the probability distribution of $V$
- $P_{T|v}$ denote the probability distribution of $T$ conditional on $V=v$
- $P_{Y|v,t}$ denote the probability distribution of $T$ conditional on $V=v, T=t$

Suppose that all the supports are finite sets. Then, we know that, by the law of total probability:

$$
P_{Y,V}(y,v)=P_{V}(v)\sum_{t\in \mathcal{T}}P_{T|v}(t) P_{Y|v,t}(y) 
$$

Now, I want to rewrite the same expression when $V$ is a **continuous** random variable. I don't want to introduce densities. If necessary, I can work with cumulative distribution functions. Could you help to provide a notationally precise statement?

Comment: The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413331 concerns the connection between integrals and sums in the context of probability distributions.

Answer (score 3):

The law of [total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) can be written in terms of the CDFs as a [Riemann-Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) integral:

$$F_X(x) = \int \limits_\mathscr{Y} F_{X|Y}(x|y) \ dF_Y(y).$$

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling to map this with my question. When $\mathcal{T}$ is not finite, is it $$F_{Y,V}(y,v)=F_{Y|V}(y|\{i\in \mathcal{V}: i\leq v\}) \times F_V(v)= \int_{\mathcal{T}} F_{Y|V,T}(y|\{i\in \mathcal{V}: i\leq v\}, t)dF_{T|V}(t|\{i\in \mathcal{V}: i\leq v\}) \times F_V(v)$$?

Comment: But what if $\mathcal{T}$ is finite?

Comment: The conditional CDF in my answer is still conditional on a single point, so $F_{X|Y}(x|y) \equiv \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant x | Y=y)$.  In the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, if $Y$ is countable (including finite) then the integral reduces to a sum taken over the mass function of $Y$.

Comment: But I think that the CDF conditional on a single point is not what I need in my specific case, because everything start from the joint of $Y$ and $V$.