# Conditional probability formula for continuous random variables

Tags: conditional-probability, continuous-data, conditional-expectation, notation

Let $V,T$ be two random variables with supports $\mathcal{V},\mathcal{T}$, respectively. Let

- $P_{V|T}$ denote the probability distribution of $V$ coditional on $T$
- $P_{V,T}$ denote the probability distribution of $(V,T)$
- $P_{T}$ denote the probability distribution of $T$, $P_{V}$ denote the probability distribution of $V$
- $P_{T|V}$ denote the probability distribution of $T$ coditional on $V$

Suppose that $\mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ are finite. Then, 
$$
E(V|T=t)= \sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}} v P_{V|T}(v|t)= \sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}} v \frac{P_{V,T}(v,t)}{P_{T}(t)}=\sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}} v \frac{P_{T|V}(t|v)P_V(v)}{P_{T}(t)}
$$
Moreover, 
$$
\underbrace{E(V|T=t)\geq 0 \leftrightarrow \sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}} v P_{T|V}(t|v)P_V(v)\geq 0}_{(*)}
$$
Now, I want to write condition $(*)$ (and in particular the right hand side)  **when $V$ and $T$ are continuous random variables**, without using probability density functions but only probability measures or cumulative distribution functions. Could you help?

---

My attempt: I managed to write $(*)$ when $\mathcal{T}$ is finite and $V$ is a continuous random variable:
$$
E(V|T=t)\geq 0 \leftrightarrow \int_{\mathcal{V}} v P_{T|V}(t|v)dP_V(v)\geq 0
$$
But I'm struggling to extend to the case when also $T$ is a continuous random variable.

Comment: $P_V$ denotes the PDF, but in the integral you write it as if it is CDF, am I wrong?

Comment: In an answer (to a different but related question) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413331/, I provide an explicit, universal formula that answers your question in terms of the CDF.  Elsewhere you can also find answers in terms of characteristic functions, moment-generating functions, and cumulant-generating functions.

Comment: $P_V$ is probability distribution and not density.